# Can't specify table name on mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am mass assigning new id numbers to things in the DB to make room for some stuff at the beginning of each table. I created a procedure that works, but when I try adding input parameters to allow scripting, it can't find the table

```
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE changeID 
( IN in_table_name varchar(64)) 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a,b INT DEFAULT 800000;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id  FROM in_table_name ORDER BY id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH cur1 INTO b;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
        UPDATE in_table_name SET id = a + 1 where id = b;
        SET a = a+1;

END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
END; 
|
delimiter ;
```

When I run this using `call changeID('users')`, I get the error:

```
[Err] 1146 - Table 'databaseName.in_table_name' doesn't exist
```

I was hoping to loop through using a simple list of commands like this so it could run unattended instead of manually changing the `in_table_name` between each execution:

```
call changeID('users');
call changeID('appointments');
call changeID('groups');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KChason got me started in the right direction, but I had to take it a little further to get the first part working from tips here: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,138495,138908#msg-138908.

```
DROP PROCEDURE
IF EXISTS `workingversion`;

delimiter |

CREATE PROCEDURE `workingversion` (IN tableName VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE a,
 b INT DEFAULT 800000 ;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v1; 
SET @stmt_text = CONCAT("CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT id FROM ",    tableName,  " ORDER BY id") ; 
PREPARE stmt
FROM
    @stmt_text ; EXECUTE stmt ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt ;
BEGIN

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM v1 ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000'
SET done = 1 ; OPEN cur1 ;
REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO b ;
IF NOT done THEN
SET @Query = CONCAT('UPDATE ',tableName,' SET `id` = ',a+1,' WHERE `id`=',b);
PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
EXECUTE stmt;

        SET a = a+1;
END
IF ; UNTIL done
END
REPEAT
    ; CLOSE cur1 ;
END ;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically pass a table name in a query, however, you can concatenate a string and then execute it as a statement. You of course want to be careful and ensure that this data has been sanitized etc. I wasn't able to test this, but something to this effect should get you going.

```
...
END IF;

SET @Query = CONCAT('UPDATE ',in_table_name,' SET `id` = ',a+1,' WHERE `id`=',b);
PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
EXECUTE stmt;
...
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Thank you, I am attempting to use what you taught me within the cursor select, but I keep getting an error for any line after this: `SET @in_table_name = in_table_name varchar(50);` I tried it with and without the varchar, DECLARE instead of SET, is there a reason I can't set it outside the loop?

Comment: I don't see the line you mentioned in your comment. Why are you resetting the variable? Which error(s) are you getting? Why don't you update your question so it can be formatted nicely?

Comment: this line here gives me the id of rows in the table I am working with, the other section you helped with is for the execution.
`DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id  FROM in_table_name ORDER BY id;`